# Make Tesseract Recognize Digits

Tags: java, opencv, xamarin.android, ocr, tesseract

After binarization:

```
Imgproc.CvtColor(mat, mat, Imgproc.ColorBgr2gray);

Imgproc.GaussianBlur(mat, mat, new OpenCV.Core.Size(5, 5), 2);

Threshold(mat, mat, 100, 255, Imgproc.ThreshBinary);
Imgproc.Dilate(mat, mat, Imgproc.GetStructuringElement(Imgproc.MorphRect, new OpenCV.Core.Size(15, 15)));
Imgproc.Erode(mat, mat, Imgproc.GetStructuringElement(Imgproc.MorphRect, new OpenCV.Core.Size(11, 11)));
```

... finding contours, detect ROI and move it to new Mat, resize to 300DPI Tesseract doesn't seem to recognize any digit.

Image after improve quality looks like this:

[image]

Tesseract have this settings:

```
tessBaseApi.SetPageSegMode(TessBaseAPI.OemTesseractCubeCombined);
tessBaseApi.SetVariable(TessBaseAPI.VarCharWhitelist, "0123456789");
```

Any solutions to make it recognize digits?

Comment: Which version of tesseract are you using? I just tested your image in Python, all characters got recognized.

Comment: I use Xamarin.Android binding

Comment: https://github.com/halkar/Tesseract.Xamarin

Comment: Well Xamarin uses [tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two) for android which supports tesseract v3.05. So I don't know if it's your version of tesseract or the tess-two wrapper. I tested your image with tesseract v4.0 with 100% accuracy.

Comment: What traineddata file are you using?

Comment: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Data-Files eng.traineddata for Version 3.04/3.05